# SelectMany converts query to Enumerable List. How to avoid it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a MVC controller action that does a database query this way:

```
var marcaciones = db.Marcacion
```

where db is the database context in Entity Framework, and Marcacion is a database table. After that instruction, `marcaciones` type becomes

```
System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[CasinosCloud.Models.Marcacion]
```

That allows to add any filter before framework actually executes the query in database.

So far, so good.

However, depending on certain condition, `marcaciones` variable is assigned in a different way.

The database model is such that `marcaciones` entity in database is a child of another entity. To get that `marcaciones` list, I can do this:

```
var marcaciones = trabajador.ServicioSupervisado.SelectMany(s => s.Marcacion).AsQueryable();
```

As you can infer from instruction above, `trabajador` is a parent database entity that have many `ServicioSupervisado` entities, which, in turn, can have many `Marcacion` entities.

Since `marcaciones` variable is the same as the `marcaciones` variable I showed before, I have to convert to `Queryable`.

After executing the above instruction, `marcaciones` type becomes;

```
{System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>d__17`2
    [CasinosCloud.Models.Servicio,CasinosCloud.Models.Marcacion]}
```

That mean query is actually converted to an Enumerable List.

All that works when no other filter is applied. When I add query filter I got problems with the second form. First, the whole web page is slower because all filters are applied in a memory list, not in the database, and second, I have problems with string comparisons, specially when I try to find a text in lowercase when in database is stored in uppercase. Of course, nothing is found in such a case.

I think the problem is reduced by solving the type issue. Why after calling `SelectMany`, the query is actually executed and converted to an Enumerable List? Is there a way to avoid this and all that to be executed in database? Maybe I should rewrite that instruction not using `SelectMany`. I tried by using `db.Marcacion.Insersect()` to do the intersection with this code, but the same problem occurs:

```
trabajador.ServicioSupervisado.SelectMany(s => s.Marcacion)
```

EDIT:

Query I want to execute in database takes the following form:

For the first way:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM Marcacion m
```

For the second way:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM Marcacion m
INNER JOIN Servicio s ON s.ServicioId = m.ServicioId
INNER JOIN Trabajador t ON t.TrabajadorId = s.TrabajadorId
WHERE t.TrabajadorId = 1069
```

EDIT 2:

For the second way, I tried with:

```
marcaciones = marcaciones.Where(m => trabajador.ServicioSupervisado.Any(s => s.ServicioId == m.ServicioId));
```

After that, when query is actually executed in database, this error happens:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'CasinosCloud.Models.Servicio'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'

Comment: Your problem is that `trabajador.ServicioSupervisado` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, not an `IQueryable<T>`.  It has nothing to do with `SelectMany`.  We can't know why `trabajador.ServicioSupervisado` isn't an `IQueryable`, as we have no idea what it is or where it comes from.

Comment: General note: if you have to call `AsQueryable()`, you're 99% probably doing it wrong. **Never** think that calling `AsQueryable()` will magically transform an in-memory `IEnumerable<T>` into a database query

Comment: @Servy yes.. you are right... I saw the entity class that EDMX generated and that property was defined this way: public virtual ICollection<Servicio> ServicioSupervisado { get; set; }... but that was generated automatically by the Entity Framework designer. That gives me the clue to not using that property... but I had the same problem at last, when using SelectMany, It also returns an ICollection. Maybe, it is not possible to do that query in completely in database.

Comment: It's going to be easier to help you if you add exactly what you want to do rather than how you approached the problem. At the moment we don't know what query  you want to execute in the database

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto if I don't use AsQuery, i cannot add more filters... for example, if I have just "var marcaciones = db.Marcacion"... I cannot do then "marcaciones = marcaciones.Where(m => m.Trabajador.TrabajadorRun.Equals(run));" if some filter applies.

Comment: @jstuardo You can't do it even if you *do* call `AsQueryable`.  You have an in memory object, not a representation of a not-yet-executed database query.  Calling `AsQueryable` doesn't change that.  Either recognize that you're using an in-memory object and intentionally use the `IEnumerable` overloads, or correct what resulted in you having an in-memory object when you wanted to have a database query.

Comment: @Servy I don't have an in memory object... when I define the varialble as queryable and can add more where's to the query,  query is actually executed in database after all filters are applied, when I explicitly call .ToList()

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I edited to the question in the final query I need to achieve.

Comment: @jstuardo Yes, when you call the LINQ methods on a queryable it changes the query run in the database, and when you call it on an in-memory object it doesn't.  So you need to not call your methods on in memory objects if you want them to run in the database.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by writing the query this way:

```
var servicios = trabajador.ServicioSupervisado.Select(s => s.ServicioId);
marcaciones = marcaciones.Where(m => servicios.Any(s => s == m.ServicioId));
```

That way query is executed when I call `ToList()`, and works in both cases I told about, being very fast in both since query is run directly in database with all filters applied.

By seeing the database log, the final query executed by Entity Framework was:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[MarcacionId] AS [MarcacionId], 
    [Extent1].[MonitorId] AS [MonitorId], 
    [Extent1].[TrabajadorId] AS [TrabajadorId], 
    [Extent1].[EmpresaId] AS [EmpresaId], 
    [Extent1].[ServicioId] AS [ServicioId], 
    [Extent1].[MarcacionFechaHora] AS [MarcacionFechaHora], 
    [Extent1].[MarcacionEntradaSalida] AS [MarcacionEntradaSalida], 
    [Extent1].[MarcacionChecksum] AS [MarcacionChecksum], 
    [Extent1].[MarcacionEquipo] AS [MarcacionEquipo], 
    [Extent1].[MarcacionEsManual] AS [MarcacionEsManual], 
    [Extent1].[MarcacionCreadoEn] AS [MarcacionCreadoEn], 
    [Extent1].[MarcacionActualizadoEn] AS [MarcacionActualizadoEn], 
    [Extent1].[MarcacionIndice] AS [MarcacionIndice]
FROM  [dbo].[Marcacion] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Trabajador] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TrabajadorId] = [Extent2].[TrabajadorId]
WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
    WHERE 3 = [Extent1].[ServicioId]
)) AND ([Extent2].[TrabajadorNombres] + N' ' + [Extent2].[TrabajadorApellidos] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~') AND ([Extent1].[MarcacionFechaHora] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[MarcacionFechaHora] <= @p__linq__2)
```